# How to change storage size type on CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmosdb (Document DB) and I've created a collection with fixed capacity (10 GB) and minimum throughput (we weren't sure that our service will get popular and therefore we wen't with the cheapest option).
[image]

Now that the service is getting popular, I expect it to reach 10GB very soon so I wanted to change the capacity type to unlimited so it can grow over time, but the only option that is available to me is the Throughput.

How can I do that?

[image: storage capacity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change a Fixed Size Collection into an Unlimited Collection.

You will have to create a new Collection, define the Partition Key, and move your data using the Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool (https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/releases)